# How can I get the song ID from MediaStore if I know the path?

Tags: android, mediastore

Currently I am getting a song ID from MediaStore by the title of the song:

```
long id = 0;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    String[] selectionArgs = {songTitle};
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(idIndex));
        }
    }
    return id;
```

This works good only if the title is not null.
Is there a direct way to get the song ID from MediaStore directly from the path of the mp3 file?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my own question since I found the solution.
The solution was to replace TITLE with DATA since DATA represents the path of the media file in MediaStore.

```
public static long getSongIdFromMediaStore(String songPath, Context context) {
    long id = 0;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    String[] selectionArgs = {songPath};
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection + "=?", selectionArgs, sortOrder);


    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, songPath);
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(idIndex));
        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: its unluckily not working for me -
my filepath is something like -
**/storage/emulated/0/Music/[Songs.PK] 01 - Bang Bang - Tu Meri.mp3** ,
using the exact same code as above, but it is not working. That is not entering in the codition - while (cursor.moveToNext()) {. I am unable to find the reason for it, can you please help?

Comment: yeah, thanks for `String[] selectionArgs = {songPath};` so it's how we can get MetaData for a specific audio file